# Surd factors do not auto cancel each other out

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

```
Simplify[Sqrt[Pr] - (Sqrt[Pr/Ra])*Sqrt[Ra]]
```

The above command should give me `0` as the simplified outcome, but it keeps generating the following
[image: The square root of Ra in the denominator does not cancel out with the other sqrt[Ra]]

However, after I manually split that fraction of surds into two separate surds, it generates the desired form
[image: The desired form]

This is annoying because in lengthy expressions it always convert fraction of surds into a single square root (as the one shown in the first picture) and it then just leaves it is without further simplification. Is there any way to let it auto-split those single square roots of fractions?

Comment: Similar questions were asked and answered many times in this forum. By default, Mathematica considers `Pr` and `Ra` as complexes and the required simplification is not valid. The following `Simplify[Sqrt[Pr] - (Sqrt[Pr/Ra])*Sqrt[Ra], 
 Assumptions -> Pr > 0 && Ra > 0]` works.

Comment: You could also use `Sqrt[a/b]-Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[b] // PowerExpand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sqrt[a/b] == Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[b]
```

does only hold if b>0

```
Simplify[Sqrt[a/b] == Sqrt[a]/Sqrt[b], Assumptions -> b > 0]
```

> True

So you get your result if you just write

```
Simplify[Sqrt[Pr] - (Sqrt[Pr/Ra])*Sqrt[Ra], Assumptions -> Ra > 0]
```

> 0

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that! Just a quick query: is there a way to assume Ra>0 only once at the start of a script such that the assumption is carried out throughout the rest of the script?

Comment: @user31899 see `$Assumptions` in the docs